# Plot XY graph from a text file

Tags: vb.net, csv, plot, text-files

I would like to plot a simple XY graph (chart type = line) with multiple series in the chart in VB.net 2015 from a file generated in Fortran. The file content is like below:

```
1,         500.00    ,         25.607    ,        5.12137E-02
2,         502.50    ,         25.479    ,        5.07049E-02
3,         505.01    ,         25.353    ,        5.02036E-02
4,         507.51    ,         25.228    ,        4.97097E-02
```

I would like to place the first two column as the X axis values and the rest columns as Y axis. 
here is what I've done so far:

```
  Private Sub field_result_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles field_result.Click    
result = "C:\Users\sep\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\sea electrod-pipe sample\sea electrod-pipe sample\bin\Debug\fort.11"
     Dim s As Stream = New FileStream(result, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read)
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s)
        Dim str As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        sr.ReadLine()
        Do While Not sr.EndOfStream

            str = sr.ReadLine
            c(0) = " "
            sarr = str.Split(c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Loop

        Chart1.Series.Add("field").ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        Chart1.Series("field").XValueType = Charting.ChartValueType.Int64
        Chart1.Series("field").XAxisType = Charting.AxisType.Primary

        Chart1.Series("field").YValueType = Charting.ChartValueType.Int64
        Chart1.Series("field").YAxisType = Charting.AxisType.Primary
        Chart1.Series("field").Points.addXY(sarr(1), sarr(3))

    End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quick question: Other than that the data was generated with Fortran, is there anything else you need with Fortran?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You should just google "vb.net create line chart", there're a lot of tutorials out there...then post any specific problems you're having getting your chart to work

Comment: @VladimirF yes here you can find my code:
Private Sub field_result_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles field_result.Click
result = "directory path"
Dim s As Stream = New FileStream(result,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s)
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
sr.ReadLine()
Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
Dim p As Point/str = sr.ReadLine
Dim c(0) As Char/c(0) = " "
Dim sarr() As String
sarr = str.Split(c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
p.X = CInt(sarr(0))
p.Y = CInt(sarr(1))
listpos.Add(p)
Loop

Comment: @VladimirF part 2: 
chart1.invalidate()
end sub 
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
                            System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        If (gp IsNot Nothing) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Blue, gp)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Don't send it in a comment to me. I am on my holiday. Edit the question to include the additional information.

Comment: @VladimirF I've modified the question, thanks for your considerations.

Comment: @VladimirF I think I have solved the problem Vladimir, thanks anyway for your heartwarming comment :)